# How to avoid the blank or white screen in Internet Explorer when page redirect?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf, networking, web-applications

I'm developing a Java EE project using ICEfaces3 framework, and now we are facing a knotty problem when every time u click a banner tab(Not limited) send a request to trigger a page redirect, since then a white screen is shown just for nearly 1sec during redirect to a new page.

This issue can be reproduced in IE7/8/9, Firefox and Chrome works fine.
So far I did much research on IE, when I open the debug tool to watch the network status I see every time the white screen displayed the network is request to *.iface url, and after processing the *.iface request within 1sec, the redirect page will be rendered.

OH, attach a NOTE, I have tested other applications such as MS-Hotmail, when I land in the hotmail login page and click sign in button, a white page is also displayed for some seconds then the redirect page rendered. This is same as my problem.

Is there any solutions to solve the IE white screen redirect issue? 
Special thanks to your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a browser-specific issue. IE clears the HTML DOM immediately as the response has been arrived, regardless of if the response headers indicates a redirect and/or if the response body contains a HTML document. Other browsers only clears the HTML DOM tree only at the moment when it's supposed to be replaced with new content.

Your best bet would be performing the request by ajax instead. The only caveat is a non-SEO-friendly link when a `<h:commandLink>` is been used.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, we can't change our application to be ajax instead as it would cost too much work. Therefore, it seems the blank screen issue can't be solved within a shot time...